# how to do order-by in hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, orm, sql-order-by

suppose Object A has a list of Object B, and Object B must have a object C, B can be order base on C.level .

In A.hbm.xml

```
<bag name="listB"
             table="T_B"
             inverse="false"
             order-by="?? what should i do here???"
         >
            <key column="ID_A" not-null="true"/>
            <many-to-many column="ID_B" class="B"/>
        </bag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order-by clause should contain the SQL snippet you would use to order the list of items.  If your ordering criteria is not located in the table T_B in your example, then you probably won't be able to accomplish what you want.  On the other hand if B contains a C and its always a one to one relationship, you could define a view in the DB the aggregates the tables and gives you a column to sort on.

Answer (score 0):

I though order-by is specified in your query? no?

exp:

```
from Document fetch all properties order by name
```

Comment: thanks for you quick reply..but sometime query is not good enough....suppose i already got the object A...which is the Document object in your query...and i say...document.getProperties()....then the return value wouldn`t be in order

Comment: Then I have to say sorry. I don't know how to set it either. I would use "Comparable" interface with "Collection.sort()" in this case, but this way I lose the beauty of query though.