# hibernate order by map association

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

i have a domain class which looks like this

```
public class User {
   ...

   @OneToMany
   @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   @JoinTable(
      name="user_result",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="result_id")
   )
   @MapKeyColumn(name="step")
   public Map<EStep, Result> getResults() {
      return results;
   }

   ...
}
```

now i am trying to write a hql which lists all of my users ordered by a property (e.g. score) of the class Result for the key EStep.STEP_1.

is it even possible to do such queries in hql?

Comment: This link may solve this .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366197/how-to-do-order-by-in-hibernate-mapping

Answer (score 1):

Yes in HSQL it is possible. But it is also possible with `Criteria`.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Cat.class);
c.createAlias("mother.kind", "motherKind");
c.addOrder(Order.asc("motherKind.value"));
return c.list();
```

hsql order by example

```
String hql = "from Survey p order by p.price asc";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: i think you got me wrong. i know how to do a sort on "simple" associations. but i want to sort on a java.util.Map